# Route component as props in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

I would like to intercept a number passed to a route :

```
routes: [{ path: '/user/:id', component: User }]
```

And get the prop in the `User` component:

```
export default {
    props: {
       id: Number
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected Number with value 2, got 
String with value "2".
```

Is there a way to natively coerce the value into a number? I looked at https://github.com/posva/vue-coerce-props but I feel I can do the same without another extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern would be to use a computed property which transforms the prop into the form you'd like to use for your component. You'd also have to update the prop definition to allow both strings and numbers.

```js
export default {
    props: {
        id: {
            validator(value) {
                return !isNaN(parseInt(propVal));
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        parsedId() { 
            return parseInt(this.id); 
        }   
    }
}
```

Then in the rest of your code, you'd use `parsedId` instead of `id` which admittedly isn't ideal. There's an [open RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/10) which would solve this by allowing you to define separate internal and external names for props.

Actually, for vue-router, take a look at the [props function](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode) in your route definition. It should allow you to map the route params into the prop structure you desire.

I think something like this would work.

```js
routes: [{ 
    path: '/user/:id', 
    component: User,
    props: route => ({ id: parseInt(route.params.id) })
}]
```